# Must one have intent that a specific food will fulfill the third meal for them?

Tags: shabbat, meal-seudah, oneg-shabbat

Being that we don't have a Kiddush for Shaleshudes (Seudah Shlishit)  is intent needed for one's eating to be counted for this or is simply eating enough?

Does this change depending on the type of food; for example, if someone does not wash but rather is Kovea Seuda through fruit or Mezonos?

Comment: I don't understand your reference to Kiddush. Why does Kiddush change anything such that this question doesn't apply to all three meals? In fact some/many people don't say Kiddush on their second meal at all, but rather just on an earlier snack.

Comment: Why would this be different from any other Mitzva and the general rules of Mitzvot Tzrikhot Kavana? Why might the kind of food being used matter? Either a food is acceptable for the Mitzva or not. There seems to be some background information and/or assumptions which you haven't shared. Please [edit] your post to better present the issues that you are having trouble with.

Comment: making kidush with a snack fulfils making kiddush with a meal. The reason this stood out to me is when making kiddush there is no mistake that one is making a meal. Without kiddush any snack on shabbos could count for the third meal. Being that there is no special introduction such as kiddush what exactly about this meal fulfills the requirement for it to count to be yotze the third meal?

Comment: I heard some people have the minhag to make Kiddush on Sholosh Seudos - can any one shed any light on this and whether they add any specific psukim to the brocho?